# Added a new line to hosts file but doesn't work

Tags: internet, dns, ip

I added this line to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1:8000 myapp.com
```

But when I access myapp.com from a web browser, it doesn't go to the IP that I listed first. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` file is about **hosts** and their names. It is used when resolving a domain name such as `myapp.com` to a specific IP address. Howewer, it is *not* used when choosing which port to connect to; you cannot use `host:port` in it; the port must always be specified when connecting – i.e. `http://myapp.com:8000/` in the browser.